# Python list comprehension modify the elements based on string match

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have python code which return the list comprehension as shown below in return code.

```
return [str(source.get(field)) for field in fields]
# one of the list output
['3', 'checkuser', '=checkuser', 'management', '', 'checkuser@gmail.com', '', 'True', "['apiusermanagement']", 'False']
```

**Requirement**

I need to check each element in list and if element first character is starting with any of ('=', '@', '|', '%') these characters then I need to append the single double quote (") in starting of that list element.

For example, 3rd element '=checkuser' in example output started with '=' so this element should be modified as '"=checkuser' and same should be part of returned list output

```
# Expected output
['3', 'checkuser', '"=checkuser', 'management', '', 'checkuser@gmail.com', '', 'True', "['apiusermanagement']", 'False']
```

I am beginner in Python and try to achieve this with minimal changes & good performance output. Any help or pointer would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the list in a variable. Then loop over the variable, adding the double quote where needed.

```
result = [str(source.get(field)) for field in fields]
for i, val in enumerate(result):
    if len(val) > 0 and val[0] in ('=', '@', '|', '%'):
        result[i] = '"' + val
return result
```

Comment: Great. This one worked for me, thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to put this logic into a function:

```
def fetch_and_map(field):
    result = str(source.get(field))
    if result.startswith("="):
        return '"' + result
    else:
        return result

return [fetch_and_map(field) for field in fields]
```

You could also do this inline as:

```
return ['"' + str(source.get(field)) if str(source.get(field)).startswith("=") else str(source.get(field)) for field in fields]
```

Note that if `source` is a dict of strings, you can make this simpler by skipping the `str()` call:

```
return ['"' + source.get(field) if source.get(field).startswith("=") else source.get(field) for field in fields]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
output = ['3', 'checkuser', '=checkuser', 'management', '', 'checkuser@gmail.com', '', 'True', "['apiusermanagement']", 'False']
output_modified = []
for string in output:
    if string != "" and string[0] in ['=', '@', '|', '%']:
        output_modified.append('"' + string)
    else:
        output_modified.append(string)
```

This will iterate over each string in `output`. If the string is not empty and begins with `'='`, `'@'`, `'|'`, or `'%'`, it will add `'"'` to the beginning of `string` and append it to `output_modified`. If not, it will simply append it to `output_modified` as-is.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
lst = ['3', 'checkuser', '=checkuser', 'management', '', 'checkuser@gmail.com', '', 'True', "['apiusermanagement']",
       'False']
lst_ex = [f'"{x}' if x and x[0] in {'=', '@', '|', '%'} else x for x in lst]
print(lst_ex)
```

output

```
['3', 'checkuser', '"=checkuser', 'management', '', 'checkuser@gmail.com', '', 'True', "['apiusermanagement']", 'False']
```